# Django: Restarting Shared Server When Changing MVC Python Files

Tags: django, apache, shared-hosting

Essentially, 
I am doing some of the development for my Django app straight on my shared server rather than on a local machine (I know that initially is the problem) however regardless, I would like to know if there is a way to restart the apache server on my shared hosted server (Bluehost) for when I modify any of the python files.

I'm not sure how the Django framework is setup, maybe restarting the webserver is not needed?

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the apache configured to run python codes? are you using fcgi, wsgi or something else?

What i do is, i use a fcgi process and restart fcgi process without the need to restart the webserver. In my case web server is nginx but it should be same in apache if you are using fcgi.

Comment: It's using fcgi. I'm not even sure how the fcgi gets executed (from .httaccess) ? Could you elaborate more perhaps on what you mean by your fcgi process that you restart?

Comment: When using nginx, i have a seperate fcgi process for each of my django projects. If you have a similar setup in apache then all you need to do restart fcgi process. You should check http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html this link and try to understand how you did configure fcgi and restart the fcgi process accordingly as you wish.